# Fitting known equation to data

Tags: r, optimization, curve-fitting, nonlinear

I have measured growth rates over a range of temperatures (temperature response curve) and would like to fit an already established equation/model to it. I'm very new to R and have trouble coding it right.

This is my data:

```
    x <- c(37.8,
   34.8,
   32.25,
   29.65,
   26.75,
   24.4,
   21.45,
   19.15,
   16.2,
   13.7,
   10.95,
   8.2,
   5.4)
    y <- c(0.0381,
   0.018133333,
   1.057033333,
   2.3395,
   2.5188,
   2.6132,
   2.398466667,
   2.082966667,
   1.687366667,
   1.389233333,
   0.9835,
   0.639833333,
   0.3757)
```

The equation I'm trying to fit is as follows:

$y=(3.5-x/10)(x/25)^{(5/2)}$

There is also another data set:

```
x2 <- c(34.8, 32.25, 29.65, 26.75, 24.4, 21.45, 19.15, 16.2, 5.4)
```

and

```
y2 <- c(0.033966667, 1.5153, 2.226266667, 2.3462, 2.096766667, 2.0986, 1.941866667, 1.5183, 0.2717)
```

I tried modifing code that I found here to my equation but have been unsuccessful so far. Can someone help with this with a step by step guide for dummies?

Updated model for my dataset:

$$y = Y_{max}\frac{T_{max}-x}{T_{max}-T_{opt}}\left(\frac{x}{T_{opt}}\right)^{(T_{opt}/(T_{max}-T_{opt}))}$$

Comment: Your function doesn't appear to contain any unknowns. In what sense is there an "fitting" going on? Also ... when you write the  "(x/25)exp(5/2)" part do you actually mean (x/25)^(5/2)? That looks a lot more like the shape of your data (but the entire function is only about 37% of what it should be). Even with that change the function isn't quite right, but it's sort of closeish.

Comment: Hi Glen, fitting is the wrong word I guess then. I basically want to see how well my data fits to the equation. There are some unknowns in the original equation that can be filled with measurements. The following equation can be used too: y=((35−x/(35-z))(x/z)^(z/(10))

Comment: With the previous version of your "updated model," y can never reach a value greater than 1. The peak for y occurs at $x=T_{opt}$, and at that value of x, y=1. I edited your question to add an additional parameter $Y_{max}$ to cover this. I also put the additional data set (which I now use for examining differences between parameter values) into your question directly, as comments (unlike questions) can be lost. Make sure that you are checking plots by eye and that you have reasonable fits before you start worrying about differences between fitted parameters from different experiments.

Answer (score 26):

**Fitting data to an equation without free parameters**

First, let's clarify what it means "to see how well my data fits to the equation" when you have a fixed equation as in your original question. You have data on $x$ and $y$, and your equation:
$$y=(3.5-(x/10))(x/25)^{5/2}$$
has no free parameters. Here's a plot; data points are circles, the equation a solid curve:

[image: original curve and data]

So to answer your original question, your data don't fit that equation very well.

**Fitting parameters of an equation to match data**

Second, "fitting an equation" generally means having a general form of a relation between $y$ and $x$ in mind, but the details of the form depend on some additional unknown parameters of the equation. "Fitting" then means using the data to estimate the *values* of the parameters that best match the data, say by minimizing the sum of the squares of the discrepancies between the curve and the data. That is what's implicit in the form of the equation in your comment. (I corrected an apparently missing parenthesis so that it matches your original parameter-free equation at $z=25$):
$$y = \frac{35-x}{35-z}\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^{(z/10)}$$
Now there is something to "fit": find the value of $z$ that comes closest to your data. The simplest R function to do this is `nls`. (The R code I used is at the end of the answer.) The best fit to your $x$ and $y$ data is provided by a $z$ value of 33.1, not the value of 25 that would match your first parameter-free equation. It comes closer, but doesn't do very well, either, substantially below most of the true values:

[image: fit z only]

It looks like your equation might have an even more general form, like:
$$y = \frac{a-x}{a-z}\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^{(z/b)}$$
where $z$, $a$ and $b$ are parameters whose values might be estimated from the data. With that more general form, you can come fairly close to your data, at $z=34.0$, $a=36.7$, and $b=17.8$:
[image]

**Dangers in fitting equations**

Third, you must be very careful if you head down this fitting path. As [John von Neumann allegedly said](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann), "With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk." Overfitting is a serious temptation when you start playing with data.

In a case like yours you have to think about what the parameters might mean in the real world. It seems that there are competing processes that lead to a peak in growth rate ($y$) at a certain temperature ($x$), and if the parameters $z$, $a$ and $b$ have definite meanings in terms of those competing processes then you might be justified in doing this type of fit. You might, say, learn something about how those processes differ from one strain of bacteria to another. But if such parameters (or the fixed values in your original equation) were simply chosen by someone to make some earlier set of data fit a particular curve then you are headed for big trouble.

**Comparing fits to different data sets**

If you want to compare the parameter values fitted to two different data sets, it's best to start by examining whether the overall fits differ between the data sets. There is a "useful and rather easily overlooked" way to do this with `nls` as Peter Dalgaard put it in a recent [answer on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-August/431620.html). (It can be found at the very bottom of the `nls` help page.)

Instead of working with separate vectors of $x$ and $y$ values from different experiments, construct a pooled data frame containing all the data. Each row should contain an $x$ value, the associated observed $y$ value, and a factor variable indicating the specific experiment. (Make sure the experiments are coded as factors, not as numbers.)

`nls` then allows you to fit different sets of parameter values to different experiments. Instead of specifying general parameters like `Topt` in your call, you can subscript the parameters by experiment, e.g. `Topt[expt]`, where "expt" is the name of the factor distinguishing experiments.

Thus you can use `anova` to compare a fit to all the data, ignoring individual experiments, against a fit that allows different parameter values for different experiments. If these fits aren't statistically distinguishable, then you shouldn't be looking at differences of individual fitted parameter values among experiments. There's an example below where I present R code.

If the fits do differ, then you can consider comparing fitted parameter values. In the limit of very large samples the fitted values should have normal distributions, but it's not clear what "large" means for nonlinear fits and the meaning might differ depending on the equation. Thus there will be questions about the validity of *p*-values.

If you are willing to assume normality, `nls` reports standard errors for the parameter values, which you can use to obtain *p*-values under that assumption. A  *z*-test can provide a rough overview, but it would probably be better to use the approach of [Welch's *t*-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test), which allows for different standard errors and degrees of freedom between two parameter estimates. To apply that approach, note that terms like $\frac{s_i^2}{N_i}$ in the formula for Welch's test are equivalent to $SE_i^2$ in the `nls` output.

**R code**

In terms of R code, it was simplest to define a general function for your temperature-response curve:

```
trcFunc <- function(x,z,a,b){((a-x)/(a-z))*((x/z)^(z/b))}
```

then give specific values for the parameters that matched your original equation, to compare your data to the curve:

```
plot(x,y)
curve(trcFunc(x,25,35,10),add=TRUE)
```

For fitting, I used the `nls` function, for example for $z$ alone

```
Zfit <- nls(y~trcFunc(x,z,35,10),start=list(z=30))
```

or for all 3 parameter values

```
ZABfit <- nls(y~trcFunc(x,z,a,b),start=list(z=30,a=35,b=10))
```

Get the fitted parameter values with

```
ZABfit
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ trcFunc(x, z, a, b)
   data: parent.frame()
    z     a     b 
33.98 36.74 17.84 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.228

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.35e-06
```

and compare data and curve:

```
plot(x,y,main="fit z, a, b")
curve(trcFunc(x,33.98,36.74,17.84),add=TRUE)
```

*New form for relation; comparing fits* With the new general form for the relation of $y$ to $x$ in an edit to the OP, a new general function for fitting is defined as:

```
newFunc <- function(x,Topt,Tmax,Ymax){Ymax*((Tmax-x)/(Tmax-Topt))*(x/Topt)^(Topt/(Tmax-Topt))}
```

For comparing two experiments, take `expt1` as the data at the beginning of the question and `expt2` as the second data set (x2,y2) toward the end, and construct a pooled data frame as suggested above. Then the fit ignoring the differences between experiments is:

```
fitPool <- nls(y~newFunc(x,Topt,Tmax,Ymax),data=newDF,start=list(Topt=25,Tmax=35,Ymax=2.5))
```

and that allowing separate parameter values for the two experiments is:

```
fitSeparate <- nls(y~newFunc(x,Topt[expt],Tmax[expt],Ymax[expt]),data=newDF,start=list(Topt=c(25,25),Tmax=c(35,35),Ymax=c(2.5,2.5)))
```

The pooled and separate fits are not significantly different:

> ```
> > anova(fitPool,fitSeparate)
> Analysis of Variance Table
> Model 1: y ~ newFunc(x, Topt, Tmax, Ymax)
> Model 2: y ~ newFunc(x, Topt[expt], Tmax[expt], Ymax[expt])
>   Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df  Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
> 1     19     1.9215                          
> 2     16     1.4410  3 0.48046  1.7782 0.1918
> ```

**Warning on choice of starting values**

Note that, as can happen in non-linear curve fitting, what you get as the "best" fit can depend on what you provide as an initial guess for the parameter values. With your data, if I provided an initial guess of 26 for $z$ and fixed values of 35 and 10 for $a$ and $b$:

```
Zfit26start <- nls(y~trcFunc(x,z,35,10),start=list(z=26))
```

the value returned for $z$ is 13.1,which doesn't fit very well at all:

[image: fit with different initial parameter choice]

This happened because the program wasn't set up to evaluate an entire range of $z$ values and got stuck in what's called a "local optimum" when it started searching from $z=26$. If I tried starting values of $z$ from 20 to 25 then the `nls` program returned an error:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

while starting values of 19 or less gave the poorly fitting estimate of 13.1 for $z$. With a non-linear curve fit you can't count on getting the "global" optimum without doing a lot of exploration.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks a lot for your detailed answer and comments! This helps me a lot!

Comment: @Kay I added an additional caution about choice of initial parameter values in non-linear curve fitting that was illustrated nicely by your data, and corrected a couple of errors in my earlier post.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks a lot for following up on that. I've noticed the same trends when I change the starting values. I'm comparing 3 different temperature settings and I can make an educated guess for the starting values to not run into the mentioned problems. There is a third parameter that can be added to the equation which gives an even better fit, but as you pointed out might not have a biological meaning. I will try and compare the equation I have with each other and see which one has the best fit AND most biological meaning.

Comment: I also have this dataset:x <- c(34.8,
          32.25,
          29.65,
          26.75,
          24.4,
          21.45,
          19.15,
          16.2,
          5.4)
y <- c(0.033966667,
          1.5153,
          2.226266667,
          2.3462,
          2.096766667,
          2.0986,
          1.941866667,
          1.5183,
          0.2717)
Which has two optima and gets me into trouble as the general equation does not seem to work very well on my end.

Comment: The choice of starting parameter values can be crucial. I had no problem with your second dataset when I used starting values of $z=30,a=35,b=10$, which ended up being very close to the optimum values ($z=33.1,a=35.1,b=12.3$). The instability may come from the way $z$ appears in your equation: increasing $z$ makes the first factor blow up (to infinity at $z=a$) and although it decreases the second factor it raises the exponent of the second factor.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks a lot again for your help with my curve. I've fitted the model to two of my datasets and was wondering how I could compare the coefficients of the two models. I want to test if the temperature optimum shift is significant. Can you point me where I could find how to do such a test? Thank you!

Comment: @Kay : Use calculus to find the temperature optimum as a general function of the parameters. Next make sure you saved the outputs from `nls` (as I did in my examples, e.g., `ZABfit`) for each model. Then use the `deltaMethod` function in the R `car` package to estimate the standard error of the the temperature maximum for each of your fits, by providing the general formula for the temperature maximum as the argument "g". You then will have for each model an Estimate of the temperature maximum and its standard error. Then you do a standard comparison of the 2 values given their standard errors.

Comment: Thanks Ed! The model summary also gives me a standard error `# Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#Topt 24.45320    0.16900  144.69   <2e-16 ***
 # Tmax 34.82563    0.13087  266.11   <2e-16 ***` Can I use those too or are they different to your approach? What do you mean with standard comparision? Like a t-test? I've done those before on a dataset but not with "just" a value and its standard error.

Comment: @Kay it seems that you are now using a different form of equation for `nls` than what we first discussed, where `Tmax` didn't seem to be a parameter itself. Depending on the new equation form there might be different or better ways to compare across experiments. Consider editing your post to add the new form at the end of the question. In the meantime, a simple approximate test is to use $\sqrt{SE_1^2+SE_2^2}$ as the estimate of the standard error of the difference between coefficients, and use that in a  _z_-test.

Comment: I've added the model that I'm using to my original question. If I understand it correctly, I can do the z-test for all my coeffiecients (`Topt, and Tmax`)?

Comment: The z-test is a good way to start. It assumes that the distributions of the parameter values among repeated experiments have normal distributions, which is true in the limit of large numbers of cases. Unfortunately, what constitutes a large number of cases for nonlinear models is a difficult problem that may differ among nonlinear models. I'll suggest another approach in an edit to my answer when I have more time in a day or two.

Comment: OMG this is awesome! Thank you so much. I just used the approach you added to your original answer and I get the following output of the anova `Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df   Sum Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
1     57    0.28152                              
2     55    0.24198  2 0.039544  4.4941 0.01557 *` But I also noticed that my coefficients are slightly different to the ones I get when I just run the datasets seperately. So according to the anova my two models are in general significant different? Now I would do the suggest Welch's t-test?

Comment: Make sure that the fits look OK before you proceed; you should show these when you publish. Slight differences in coefficients of combined versus individual analyses maybe aren't surprising. You have shown that the fits differ significantly, so you can look at coefficient differences between fits. Some might challenge the assumption of normality of fitted coefficient values needed for the Welch t-test, but it's probably the best you can do. The significant difference of fits (which only depends on normality of residual errors) supports the idea that there should be differences in coefficients.

Comment: Ok, I will check that. I don't want to speak for everyone in my field but I am relatively sure that most of my colleagues are not so fluent in statistics. As as long as I point out my assumption I guess it should be fine. Thank you very much EdM for being my personal statistician! Where did you learn all this? Is there a good book you can recommend?