# Finding parameters of a given function

Tags: regression, data-visualization, nonlinear-regression

I have this following relation

$$N = \dfrac{(113834700(3000-c)(1-e^{-(Xn)/(3000-c)})}{n}$$

I also have a set of values for $N$ and $X$, these are vectors. So, we have a scatter plot $N$ vs $X$.

We have to fit the data ($N$ and $X$) with the above relation and thereby have to find $c$ and $n$, which are scalars.
How do I do this?

Comment: At first you need to understand which type of distance will satisfy you. Is Euclidean distance OK?

Comment: I wanted to give one answer, but there are so many pitfalls about it so I would better recommend you to take a look at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization and choose method appropriate for your data.

Comment: Non Linear Regression might do the trick here. If you use R, try the `nls` function.

Comment: @Greenparker I tried but kept getting some error messages in R.  Could you please help me out with the R syntax for solving this?

Comment: Avogadro's number or not, try to choose units such that the magnitudes of all coefficients and data are "near" one, and within a small number of orders of magnitude of each other. Otherwise, you will just compound your solution difficulty with possible numerical problems in the optimizer. Having and inputting to the optimizer a good initial estimate of the optimal values of c and n will also help.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Couldyou please help me out with the syntax in R

Comment: @Debdatta Sinha Roy , sorry R is not my thing. But you will need to get you equation and data entered in a manner compatible with whatever nonlinear least squares solver you use.

Comment: I suspect that noticing that there is really only one parameter, (3000-c)/n, is part of the assignment.

Comment: If this is for homework or a similar type of assignment, please add the `self-study` tag and read [this page on policy](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Also note that questions specific to R or other language syntax are not for this site; try R-help or StackOverflow, etc.

Comment: @EdM No it's not a homework or assignment

Answer (score 1):

As @JimBaldwin noted in a comment, there really is only 1 free parameter to fit in your equation, $(3000-c)/n$. If your code for `nls` or another nonlinear curve fitting routine included both $c$ and $n$ as separate parameters, then it would not be surprising for the routine to run with errors: there is an infinite set of $c$ and $n$ paired values that could "fit." So solve that problem by defining another variable, call is $a$:

$$a=\frac{3000-c}{n}.$$

It also can be easier to avoid accidental errors by avoiding unusual or large constant terms. I'd simply divide all the $N$ values by the constant 113834700 to start, so that there's less chance for error in writing the formula to submit to the fitting routine. Let's say:

$$B= \frac{N}{113834700}.$$

Then you are fitting a simple relation:

$$B=a\left(1-e^{-\frac{X}{a}}\right),$$

which will minimize the chance of errors both in your coding and in the routine.

As with any nonlinear fitting, it's important to start with a good initial estimate for your unknown parameter $a$, and to be prepared to test carefully to make sure that you have found a global minimum for residual squared error rather than some local minimum. I have some examples of R code for `nls` on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/171191/28500) in a similar context, which illustrates some of the considerations.

Also, make sure that the value of 113834700 is truly a constant and not a fitted value from someone else's analysis of another data set, for which you should be estimating a new value from your data set. That type of problem arose in the question I linked in the previous paragraph. If you do only have 1 free parameter, you could use the `optim` function instead of `nls` in R.

Comment: I only see your answer after I have posted my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209068/debugging-in-r-when-using-nls/209111#209111 .  Your final paragraph matches with what I concluded using the data posted in that other question.  I concluded his model is lousy, and that hard-coded multiplicative constant "ain't cutting it". I introduced another parameter in its place and got a much better fit,.