# Debugging in R when using nls

Tags: r, data-visualization, model, nls

How to correct a nls estimator when I get an error message that: step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562

The full problem:

```
Y = c(0.056,0.408,1.4345,2.285,4.79,4.81,6.52,9.105,13.935,22.55)

X = c(0,1,5,10,15,20,30,40,50,60)

plot(X,Y)

fit = nls(Y ~ (113834700*(3000-c)*(1-exp(-(X*n)/(3000-c))))/n, start=list(c=1000,n=1))
```

I have also tried several starting values but keep getting the same error messsage

Comment: Is `n` the sample size here or some other constant that needs to be estimated?

Comment: @Greenparker Just a constant that needs to be estimated, nothing with the sample size. Both n and c are scalars and needs to be estimated.

Comment: The non linear function that you want to fit does not seem to be identifiable for $c$ and $n$. If I write $a = (3000-c)/n$, then the function becomes $113834700*a(1-\exp(X/a)$.

Answer (score 2):

To use a technical term, I believe the optimizer choked on your problem.  As @Greenparker pointed out, you have essentially only one parameter in your model, what he calls $a = (3000 - c)/n$.  With the Greenparker parameterization, it is not a nice or good fitting model, and it's hard to get any decent fit even for individual data points (other than the first).

Using the Greenparker parameterization, the best fit I was able to get was with

```
a = 3.1597e-06
```

which results in residuals (LHS - RHS) of

```
0.0560 -359.2795 -358.2530 -357.4025 -354.8975 -354.8775 -353.1675 -350.5825 -345.7525 -337.1375
```

So I introduced a new parameter to be estimated, $joe$, in addition to the Greenparker $a$.  In your notation, this would be:

```
Y ~ joe * a * (1-exp(-X/a))
```

I obtained best fit with

```
joe = 0.3005
a = 4.5016e+04
```

which results in residuals (LHS - RHS) of

```
0.0560    0.1076   -0.0676   -0.7191    0.2841   -1.1975   -2.4903   -2.9074   -1.0788    4.5354
```

This is a much better behaved model, and doesn't cause optimizers fits. I didn't use nls, but I suspect nls will be able to handle this model.  I have no idea whether this is an acceptable or useful model for your purposes, but your model with hard-coded multiplicative constant of 113834700 doesn't really seem to fit your data.  If you think there is a strong basis for your original model, perhaps you should check your derivation, and make sure that units, constants, etc. are all correct - if not, that could explain the lousy model you had.

Edit: Also note that your data point of X = 0 will always produce a fitted value of 0 (presuming $ a \ne 0$), no matter the parameter values, and therefore the LHS - RHS residual for that point is always your Y value of 0.056.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Which method did you use?

Comment: I used a few different Quasi-Newton (BFGS) solvers in another environment. My solvers made no "small residual" approximation as I think nls does, which gives it more robustness.  Nevertheless, I suspect nls can handle my model with a and joe ... especially if you use my final values as your starting values :).