# (How) Can I fit a dataset with some parameters fit globally?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, logistic-curve

I want to fit some sigmoidal curves that follow the following equation:

```
bottom+(top-bottom)/(1+10**((logIC50-x)*HillSlope))
```

the parameters top and bottom should be constant throughout several data sets, the other parameters can vary within some sets depending on the experimental conditions. Is there a way I can globally fit some parameters while fitting others locally? 
If someone could even help me with getting this done in a programming langruage I would be even more happy. I am using Python 2.7 and was programming in R quite some time ago. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How sure are you that your data are well fit by this type of 4-parameter logistic model? Dose-response curves for drugs can exhibit [hormesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormesis) with stimulation rather than inhibition at low levels. Then a more complicated model would be required.

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question:It is an Enzyme inhibited by an inhibitor- so I guess hormesis should not play a role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to fit some parameters globally and others locally, in a way that allows you to test whether there are differences among parameter values among some conditions (e.g., do IC50 values or Hill coefficients differ among a set of cell lines). In R, you can use the square-bracket indexing feature in the `nls` package; parameters that are indexed are calculated locally (by indexed group), while others are calculated globally. Peter Dalgaard gives a worked example of how to do this on an [R-help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-August/431620.html); as he notes, this useful capacity "is rather easily overlooked." It is also demonstrated, perhaps a bit cryptically, at the very bottom of the help page for `nls`. Part of my [answer to another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/171191/28500) on non-linear fitting also shows how to use this bracketing feature.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to construct the fitting function like so:

```
if (data in dataset 1):
    bottom+(top-bottom)/(1+10**((logIC50_1-x)*HillSlope_1)) # "_1"
elif (data in dataset 2):
    bottom+(top-bottom)/(1+10**((logIC50_2-x)*HillSlope_2)) # "_2"
elif (data in dataset 3):
    bottom+(top-bottom)/(1+10**((logIC50_3-x)*HillSlope_3)) # "_3"
else:
    raise Exception('Data was no from a known dataset') # nice to know
```

Comment: that is also a very interesting solution! Do you think it would be practicably for fitting?

Comment: In terms of practicality, this type of code does allow fitting a combination of both global and datase-specific parameters.