# Errors associated to 1-parameter and 2-parameter fits

Tags: dataset, error

I am trying to fit some data with a function in Python; 
I have tried having only one free parameter (let's call this parameter "A"), and then using the same function but with two free parameters ("A" and "B") (I turn a fixed number into the free parameter "B"). I have then looked at the errors associated to the best-fit values printing the covariance matrix.

However, in the case of 2 free parameters I get an error (associated to the best-fit value for parameter "A") which is much bigger than in the case of the one-parameter fit.

Shouldn't it be the opposite case? If I am right expecting a smaller error in case of more parameters, do you have an idea of why I can get a bigger error with more parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a non-linear fit? If so, the starting choices for the parameter values might send you to a local optimum that is not the global optimum. If that affected your 2-free-parameter model, its predictions could be poor. Plots of your data points and fits, and the forms of the equations, would help inform an answer. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/171154/28500) for some examples of the problems that can arise from different choices of starting parameter values.